# Set default for a datetime attribute in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, simple-form, default-value

I want to pre-assign 1448607600 (=2015-11-27 07:00:00 +0000) to a datetime attribute called starts_at in a simple_form. I did the following but didn't work. Pls help!

```
<%= f.input :starts_at, input_html: { value: Time.at(1448607600) } %>
```

I also did the following but no luck:

```
<%= f.input :starts_at, input_html: { value: Time.at(1448607600).to_s.to_datetime) } %>
```

Comment: I think you should assign this value in the controller action such as `@some_object.starts_at = Time.at(1448607600)`, so then this value will be used in the form.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better if you assigned the default date in the conroller as @Mareq suggested in the comment, but you could also do it with a callback in the model

Assuming that you have a model named Resource, in controller you could do this:

```
@my_object = Resource.new
@my_object.starts_at = Time.at(1448607600)
```

Or in the model you could have this:

```
DEFAULT_TIME = 1448607600.freeze
after_initialize :set_default_time, :if => :new_record?

private
def set_default_time
  self.starts_at = Time.at(DEFAULT_TIME)
end
```

In both cases in the `new` view you would have something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @my_object do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :starts_at %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which errors you are getting, but DateTime.strptime function should get you a valid DateTime object that you can format how you like

```
<%= f.input :starts_at, input_html: { value: DateTime.strptime("1448607600",'%s').to_s } %>
```